# What's the reason of "b" being larger in height than capital "P"?

Tags: winforms, .net-core, fonts, highdpi

I have a simple WinForm with a Label (text: tabPage).

In 100% scale:

[image]

However when I move the form to a 250% display:

[image]

As you can see, "P" is smaller in height than "b".

- Font is standard Windows11 font: Segoe UI 9pt
- Form is set to Dpi in its AutoScaleMode
- CSProj has PerMonitorV2 option defined
- .NET SDK 7
- VS2022
- 2 displays (100%, 250%)
- Start on 100%, move to 250%

What's the sense behind this kind of scaling these letters?

Answer (score 0):

It is fairly common for fonts to be designed visually so the lowercase letters are taller than the capitalized letters. This is a design choice for visual effect. So the b is always supposed to be larger if you have the resolution to accomplish that (e.g. 600 DPI laser printer).

At 100% your letters are 9 pixels high. So if the b scales to 9.1 pixels and the P scales to 8.9 pixels they both have to be displayed at 9 pixels. At 250% 9.1 becomes 22.75 and 8.9 becomes 22.25 so the b becomes 23 pixels and the P is 22 pixels.

Note the numbers are just hypothetical examples, I don't have the exact values.

This link outlines the reasons for the lowercase being larger - [Quora Answer](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-minuscule-letters-go-higher-than-capital-letters-in-most-fonts).

Comment: Thank you! Do you know what is the theoretical reason behind this visual effect? I got that it's a choice by designer. But what is the intention behind it? Why is this better than a common sized "bP"?

Comment: I updated the answer with a link to explain the theoretical reason.